# Bypass Javascript Debug Prevention in Firefox

Tags: debugging, anti-debugging, javascript

I've looked around, and can't find an answer for my specific question. The closest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53970719).

I'm trying to reverse engineer some suspicious Javascript, but it repeatedly calls a debugger statement, preventing any meaningful use of breakpoints. The question linked above describes some methods for Chrome, but I was curious if this was possible in Firefox?

Comment: This should be possible using the FF Remote Protocol. Using the [Debugger API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API) you can write a script that listens for `onDebuggerStatement` [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API/Debugger#debugger_handler_functions) and automatically resumes execution.

Comment: Run it through some kind of AST analyser and remove the debugger statements?